# How to generate UI elements in JavaFX? For eg. generate 10 buttons

Tags: java, javafx

How can you generate for eg. 10 buttons in JavaFX Builder? I don't want to insert them manually.
I need this to create a virtual shop. And i want to have N products on a page, but i need text, image, etc for every product and if i don't know how many products i will have i can't put there 10 of them from the start, because maybe i will have more or less and then there will be blank images with no text set. I hope that my question is clear.

I would like to get 1 product from my database and create a textbox and a button for it. If i get 5 objects from my database i would like to create 5 textboxes and 5 buttons and so on.

Comment: Start with creating one. Then put that in a for-loop.

Comment: `ListView` or `TableView` may work for you. You'll need custom cells though for sure...

Answer (score 0):

So say you were to extract the full list of Objects from your database into your running program, then you could write code that looks something like

```
foreach(Object in Objects) do
MakeTextBox
MakeButton
MakeImage
Insert TextBox, Button and Image
```

So without ever having used JavaFX in any meaningful way I could hint you towards doing something like this:

```
    //This is the incoming package, I will assume this is a JSONArray for now since it seems obvious enough and I will assume it's called jarray_stock
    for(int i = 0; i < jarray_stock.length(); i++){
       Button b = new Button();
       TextBox t = new TextBox();
       Image i = new Image();

       parent.add(b);
       parent.add(t);
       parent.add(i);
    }
```

Now you just have to take that and replace my button textbox image with the actual appropriate classes for JavaFX and replace the parent.add with the actual methods to add that to your Frame or whatever you're actually using.

Of course if you know how many elements you need to generate you can replace jarray_stock.length() with any number you need.